# Frequent change of file-system to read-only

Tags: filesystem, fsck

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 on my relatively new laptop. Initial few days, everything worked fine, but then suddenly I started getting a strange problem. After every 2-3 days, the file-system was becoming read-only. I was unable to save/download anything in the installation drive and the system hanged if I attempted to do so, after which I needed to force restart.
I had to run fsck in the repair mode to get it fixed (temporarily). There I used to get the following messages:

```
"Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.
UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY: RUN FSCK MANUALLY.
fsck / [886] terminated with status 4.
Filesystem has errors: /"
```

Then it stopped here and I had to restart again, after which it asked whether I want to repair or not, then the system ran properly. After a day or 2, again I used to face exactly the same problem.

The problem become more frequent in the last few days, and even after running the fsck and restarting, was not solving the problem. I re-installed the OS a couple of days back, but even after that, the problem exists. Though it is not that frequent now, but still at times, the file-system becomes read-only and the system stops behaving normally, and I have to run fsck in the repair mode, which makes the whole thing normal.

Yes I keep my laptop switched on for long hours and it does get heated up.

Please help.
Thanks,
Anuj

Comment: What is your default file-system?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you run some tools to check your disc for bad sectors or problems. You can make this by:

1. Going to your disc manufacturer and see if they have a tool for checking disc problems
2. Download and use some programs that check disc for problems, like:

[Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/)

[Hiren Boot CD](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd)

Believe it or not, Windows Scandisk is also a good tool.

I would download and burn to a CD, boot that CD, and run HDD tools to check for errors.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I checked the harddisk with HDD Regenerator, and found the hard disk is infected with too many bad sectors. HDD Regenerator could repair many of them, but stopped in the middle. Is there any solution other than changing my harddisk?

Comment: I would say try to run HDD Regenerator (or other) several times, to see if it solves your bad sectors. Also try to zero your harddrive, there's a tool on that CD that does that. If those don't work, buy a new harddisc.

Comment: @Anuj I am also facing exactly same issue as you described in the question, Can you please tell me how did you solved??
I am really worried about it.

Comment: @Rupesh Backup as much as you can, but usually those discs are better of replacing by new ones.

Comment: @LnxSlck Thanks for your reply. When I run ```sudo fsck -fy``` to fix that temporirly, then it get fixed showing non-contigous memory of 1.3% but again happen after 2 days ??
Should I get a new hard disc or write off the block sectors by electronic guy?

Comment: @Rupesh My advice is backup what you can and replace that disc

Comment: Thanks @LnxSlck going to replace the hard disc then. But can you please tell what these contigous memory mean here??

Comment: @Rupesh I would need to see the full error log, but it could be the memory errors caused by fsck. non-contiguous memory is just a way how memory blocks are assigned

Comment: @LnxSlck Can you please look at the important error logs that I had today, (if you don't mind) https://pastebin.com/rPrj1gks ?

Comment: @LnxSlck If you get some time please check the logs once.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you may have some file system corruption, possibly caused by a failing hard disk. (Normally this is the only way for the system to spontaneously mark the file system as read-only, to prevent further damage.) Try running:

```
dmesg | less
```

And scroll to near the bottom to see if there are errors related to your file system and disk. Look for messages about uncorrectable read or write errors (probably on sda), or file system errors (e.g. messages about ext3 or ext4 errors).  then investigate whether the disk itself is failing (in which case you'll need to get a new one), or whether it's just a logical failure (in which case you can probably repair the file system with fsck to fix your problem).

**Another issue:**

If your filesystem supports journaling try to disable it and see. To disable journaling

`sudo /usr/sbin/diskutil disableJournal /path-to-your-disk`